# difficulty reading online xml content with python, xml.etree.ElementTree and urllib

Tags: python-3.x, xml, urllib

I am reading XML online in an RSS feed using python, xml.etree.ElementTree and urllib.
My code seems to be straightforward but is not giving me the results that I want
No matter what I do it always returns what looks like all the data in the XML stream

I am open to better suggestions on how to read specific strings into lists

see my code below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import request

title_list = []  


def main():
    try:
        response = request.urlopen("https://www.abcdefghijkl.xml")
        rsp_code = response.code
        print(rsp_code)
        if rsp_code == 200:
            webdata = response.read()
            print("1")
            xml = webdata.decode('UTF-8')
            print("2")
            tree = ET.parse(xml)
            print("3")
            items = tree.findall('channel')
            print("4")
            for item in items:
                title = item.find('title').text
                title_list.append(title)

            print(f"title_list 0 is, {title_list}")
            print("5")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred  {str(e)}')


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone, I figured it out after an awesome Udemy video. I eventually used the bs4 library(beautiful soup)python library and requests. Heres the code below

```
import bs4
import requests

title_list = []


def main():
    try:
        result = requests.get("https://abcdefghijk.xml")
        res_text = result.text
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res_text, features="xml")
        title_tag_list = soup.select('title')
        for titles in title_tag_list:
            title = titles.text
            title_list.append(title)
     
        print(f"title_list 0 is, {title_list}")
        print("5")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred  {str(e)}')


main()
```